# Store javascript return value of a function to the respective Asp Control OnClick event at server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Lunch" CausesValidation="false" 
    CssClass="bigbuttons" 
    style="background:url(../App_Themes/Images/green-box.gif)" 
    Font-Bold="True"  ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Large" 
    OnClientClick="openmodalWin(); return false;"  />
<br />
```

javascript

```
function openmodalWin() {
        var CloseTImeOfPopUp = window.showModalDialog("ClockPopUP.aspx", "Clock", 
                                  "dialogWidth:550px;dialogHeight:350px,");
}
```

As you can see, I'm calling the javascript function "openmodalWin" on the ButtonClick event. I checked that the function is returning CloseTimeofPopUp sucessfully and I am able to display it via an `Alert()`.

*[Moderator Edit: I want the returned value of that function to be sent to the server so that I can store it in the database?]*
<strike>I want the return value from the javascript function,  i can store on the same server side code i.e. Button1_OnClick() event and then i can store it to database.</strike>

Please tell me how i can do this ?

Comment: Can you fix your spelling and grammar? It's very hard to understand your question.

Comment: @Dharmendra Singh: I've attempted to correct the grammar and phrasing to help make your question more clear, but if I have somehow changed the meaning of your question, please leave a comment here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to Habib.OSU
in the page you are opening with showModalDialog 
you should return the value like this...
javascript in the Modal Dialog Page:

```
function ReturnVal(valToReturn) {
        window.returnValue = valToReturn;
        window.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of `CloseTimeOfPopUp` in a hidden variable (defined with runat="server") and then you can access that in the code behind.

In aspx page you can do:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidden1" />
```

In javascript

```
function openmodalWin() {
        var CloseTImeOfPopUp = window.showModalDialog("ClockPopUP.aspx", "Clock", "dialogWidth:550px;dialogHeight:350px,");
        document.getElementById('hidden1').value = CloseTImeOfPopUp;
        }
```

In code behind in C#

```
var myVal = hidden1.Value;
```